# Get result set from the same table for tree view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, distinct

I'm trying to implement a tree view by getting data from the following table, all the following ids are varchars:

```
     user_id   name  R_id R_name  mgr_id   mgr_name
     ----------------------------------------------
     61        a     64    c       65       b
     62        a     66    c       65       b
     63        b     64    c       65       b
     64        c     65    b       65       b
     65        b     NULL  NULL    NULL     NULL
     66        c     65    b       65       b
```

R_id, mgr_id are in turn columns in the same table User
Now I would like to get the following result set:

```
   user_id      name     Parent
   ----------------------------
   65           b         NULL
   66           c         65
   64           c         65
   63           b         64
   62           a         66
   61           a         64
```

This is the query I'm using but it seems a bit complex, I'm sure there should be an easier way to handle this:

```
    CREATE TABLE #DT
   (
    user_id VARCHAR(10),
    name VARCHAR(100),
    parent VARCHAR(10)
   )

INSERT INTO #DT
SELECT DISTINCT 
    mgr_id as user_id,
    mgr_name as name ,
    NULL AS parent 
FROM 
    Users

INSERT INTO #DT
SELECT DISTINCT 
    user_id as user_id,
    name as name ,
    mgr_id AS parent   
FROM
    Users

INSERT INTO #DT
SELECT DISTINCT
    mgr_id as user_id,
    mgr_name as name ,
    R_id AS parent 
FROM
    Users

SELECT  * FROM #DT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original query brings back duplicates as `DISTINCT` is only applied on each query, not on the overall result. If this is important to you you can use ([DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=447831e4d0885238d75d266823760512))

```
SELECT v.user_id,
       v.name,
       v.parent
FROM   users
       CROSS apply (VALUES (1,mgr_id,mgr_name,NULL),
                           (2,user_id,name,mgr_id),
                           (3,mgr_id,mgr_name, R_id) ) v(source, user_id, name, parent)
GROUP  BY v.source,
          v.user_id,
          v.name,
          v.parent
```

Otherwise a simpler version that removes these is

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.user_id,
                v.name,
                v.parent
FROM   users
       CROSS apply (VALUES (mgr_id,mgr_name,NULL),
                           (user_id,name,mgr_id),
                           (mgr_id,mgr_name, R_id) ) v(user_id, name, parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION for this. UNION effectively already applies a SELECT DISTINCT by default. You also only need to apply the column aliases on the first SELECT statement.

```
SELECT mgr_id AS user_id, mgr_name AS name, NULL AS parent FROM Users
UNION
SELECT user_id, name, mgr_id FROM Users
UNION
SELECT mgr_id, mgr_name, R_id FROM Users
```